# PDF not matching histogram of synthetic ratios of independent beta

Tags: python, density-function, beta-distribution

The PDF of the ratios of independent beta variables is described in http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/03610920008832632#.U9J02vldUcC

To explore the implications, i created an implementation in python.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.special import hyp2f1, betaln


def ratios_beta_like(a1, a2, b1, b2, w):
    if w < 0:
        return -np.inf
    logA = betaln(a1, b1) + betaln(a2, b2)
    if w <= 1:
        return (betaln(a1 + a2, b2) + (a1 - 1) * np.log(w) - logA
            + np.log(hyp2f1(a1 + a2, 1 - b1, a1 + a2 + b2, w)))
    else:
        return (betaln(a1 + a2, b1) + (-a2 - 1) * np.log(w) - logA
            + np.log(hyp2f1(a1 + a2, 1 - b2, a1 + a2 + b1, 1. / w)))
```

But it doesn't look correct to me. How have I misunderstood the paper? or is there a mistake in my implementation?

---

For example:

```
bins = np.exp(np.linspace(-9.21, 9.21, 101))

plt.xscale("log")
a2, b2 = a1, b1 = (1.18176, 2.75744)
plt.plot(bins, [np.exp(ratios_beta_like(a1, b1, a2, b2, w)) for w in bins])
plt.hist(np.random.beta(a1, b1, 1000000) / np.random.beta(a2, b2, 1000000),
          bins, normed=True, alpha=0.5)
plt.show()
```

[image: output]

How have I misunderstood the paper? or is there a mistake in my implementation?

Comment: Not everyone can access the article you posted. Would you mind including their specification for the ratio? Besides, in general it is better if questions are standalone

Comment: Let Xi ~ beta (ai, bi), i = 1, 2, be independent standard beta
variables. The random variable w=X1/X2 has density... The formulas do not copy and paste. I can re-type them but if I am misinterpreting then my re-type will show the wrong thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not in the formulas nor the Python implementation but in what you are actually plotting, which does not correspond to the histogram of the data. See the following R code to check how the histogram of the data does not look like your plot:

```
x = rbeta(1000000,1.18176, 2.75744)/rbeta(1000000,1.18176, 2.75744)
hist(x)
hist(log(x),breaks=100)
```

In conclusion, what you need to compare is the theoretical density with the histogram of the data.

Comment: http://www.ebyte.it/library/docs/math04a/PdfChangeOfCoordinates04.html is a helpfull explonation of whut I was doing rong.